# Terraform property for specifying the plan in Azure Container Apps Environment

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure, azure-container-apps

How to specify plan type = `Consumption and Dedicated workload profiles` for Azure Container Apps Environment using `terraform 3.49.0`. I am using below snippet:

```
# main.tf
resource "azurerm_container_app_environment" "aca_env" {
    for_each = { for aca_env in var.aca_envs : aca_env.name => aca_env}
  name = each.value.name
  ...
}

# .tfvars
aca_envs = [
  {
    name                 = "myacaenv"
    resource_group_name  = "myrg"
    location             = "West Europe"
    subnet_id            = "mysubnet"
    internal_load_balancer_enabled = true
    tags                 = {}
    roles = []
  }
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT March 2024**

The latest terraform version (`3.97.1`) now support workload profile (see [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/container_app_environment#workload_profile)):

```
resource "azurerm_container_app_environment" "example" {
  name                       = "my-environment"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example.id
  workload_profile {
    name                  = "Consumption"
    workload_profile_type = "Consumption"
    minimum_count         = 0
    maximum_count         = 1
  }
}
```

**Original POST**

Terraform does not support it yet (see related issue on [github](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/21747)).

You could use the [azapi](https://github.com/Azure/terraform-provider-azapi) provider to deploy a container app with a preview plan:

```tf
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azapi = {
      source  = "Azure/azapi"
    }
  }
}

resource "azapi_resource" "aca_env" {
  type      = "Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments@2022-11-01-preview"
  parent_id = azurerm_resource_group.rg.id
  location  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  name      = "my-aca-env-name"
  body   = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      appLogsConfiguration = {
        ...
      }
      workloadProfiles = [
        {
          name = "workload-profile-name"
          workloadProfileType = "workload-profile-type"
        }
      ]
      ...
    }
 })
}
```

Bicep/ARM documentation for container app environment can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.app/managedenvironments?pivots=deployment-language-bicep) .

Comment: Hi, Is there Az PowerShell command to update the plan for ACA Environment ?

Comment: why use azapi and not simply azurerm_container_app resource?

Comment: `azurerm_container_app_environment` does not support dedicated workload for the moment, as per the link to the related github issue

Comment: ah got.  reading through various github issues related to this - you may need to build the container app , not just environment with azapi.  i've actually started moving away from terraform and just using python + azcli package.  doesnt seem like terraform code is very vendor agnostic - which was my hope when moving towards it.

Comment: Terraform code is agnostics when it s come to pure infrastructure: VM / networking etc. Container App is an azure specific product so can't be agnostic really.

Comment: @Thomas I think [this](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/21747) is [implemented](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/3.97.1/docs/resources/container_app_environment) now. Lets update the answer !

Comment: Just updated the answer